# Code to remove DOM element doesn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that when you click on one of the list items it'll completely disappear, however what I've done hasn't seemed to have done the trick. I've attached snippets of the code below and here's the link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZMRNX) if you so wish to have a look at it from there. Thanks in advance.

Edit:  I should've clarified this at the begging, but the problem is in my javascript code, specifically the `removeItem` function

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const itemList = document.getElementById('item');

form.addEventListener('submit', addItem);

function addItem(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var textItem = document.getElementById('text-item').value;

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'item-group';
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textItem));
  itemList.appendChild(li);
}

const itemGroup = document.getElementByClassName('item-group');

itemGroup.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

function removeItem(e){
  if(e.target.itemList.contains('item-group')){
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')){
      var li = e.target.parentElement;
      var ul = getElementsByName('ul');
      ul.removeChild('li')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family:arial;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

#header{
  margin:20px 30px;
  background: #2cc36b;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}

#header h1{
  background: #26A65B;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:40px;
  padding:5px;
  width:260px;
  margin:20px auto;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#header input[type="text"]{
  width:400px;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

#main{
  margin:25px 100px 0 100px;
  border:2px solid #D2D7D3;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding:10px;
}

#main h3{
  margin:10px 10px -2px 30px;
  font-size:30px;
}

#main input[type="text"]{
  margin:10px 2px 8px 30px;
  padding:12px;
  width:150px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background:#f4f4f4;
  color:#111111;
  padding-right:30px;
}

#main input[type="submit"]{
  padding:10px;
  background:#BDC3C7;
  font-size:17px;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color:#001f3f;
}

#main input[type="submit"]:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#main ul{
  list-style: none;
}

#main li{
  padding:15px;
  margin:0 25px 10px 0;
  border:1px solid #BDC3C7;
  border-radius:5px;
}

#main li:hover{
  background: #FF4136;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Item Lister </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <h1> Item Lister </h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search through your items..." id="filterSearch"/>
  </div>
    <div id="main">
      <h3> Add items </h3>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item..." id="text-item"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
      <h3> My items </h3>
      <ul id="item">
        <li class="item-group"> Example 1 </li>
        <li class="item-group"> Example 2 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Liam My bad. It's to do with my javascript code, specifically the `removeItem` function

Comment: You never call `removeItem`? Obviously it's not going to work if you never call it?!

Comment: I was about to comment the same than @Liam You have to add an event that calls `removeItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of errors in your code:

There is no `itemList` property - you want `classList`:

```
if(e.target.itemList.contains('item-group')){
// should be:
if(e.target.classList.contains('item-group')){
```

You'll also need to make sure you listen for click events. You need to add something like:

```
document.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
```

When you reference your `li` and `ul` tags in your removeItem function, you are looking for strings instead of the variables. Also, there's no method named `getElementsByName`:

```
var li = e.target.parentElement;
var ul = getElementsByName('ul');
ul.removeChild('li')
// should be:
e.target.parentElement.removeChild(e.target);
```

I've updated your codepen with the changes where the function is working here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMxRMa

Comment: Also, in the codepen the click event listener is not registered but I assume in your actual code it is.

Comment: Updated my answer, make sure you add an event listener to call `removeItem` like you did for `addItem`.

Comment: Sorry, I've also updated mine. It still doesn't work having added the event listener @skyline3000

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working codepen, please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

After your code update :
this line

```
const itemGroup = document.getElementByClassName('item-group');
```

is missing an 's' should be something like this

```
const itemGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('item-group');
```

and that returns an object, im not sure if you can add an EventListener to an object

So i would suggest the solution below

add a click event to your 'li' element when you create it

something like this

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
```

and to delete it

```
var li = e.target;
var ul = e.target.parentElement;
ul.removeChild(li)
```